# How to create a simple HTTPS server in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, python-requests

Various web sources give a version of the below code:

```
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl
import socketserver


httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='localhost.pem', server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

Note: localhost.pem contains both key and certificate.

But when I set Firefox browser to point to this proxy and try to access an HTTPS enabled site, I get an error from the browser:

```
"Failed to establish a secure connection"
```

I tried to reach an HTTPS website through a Python requests client as well but to no avail.

The certificate was generated using the command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout localhost.pem -out localhost.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

Also this certificate was added to the Firefox trust Authorities.

The issue has been observer on both Mac Mojave and Windows 10, with Python 3 and OpenSSL versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019 and OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

How can I create a simple HTTPS server in Python?

Comment: [Have a look here](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596)

Comment: Have you verified the problem is actually with your code and not, say, with your certificate? What hostname is the certificate for?

Comment: @JenilDave doesn't work.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, the issue definitely seems like is with the code, generated the certificate using : "openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes" The issue has been observer on both Mac Mojave and Windows 10, with Python 3 and openssl versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019 and OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

Comment: @gkns That command doesn't really say anything about the validity of the certificate. The command creates an unsigned certificate with custom input. Did you provide useful input for the certificate? Does Firefox expect a signing CA? Does it expect a matching hostname? On my system, Firefox complains that the certificate is not for the host ``0.0.0.0:4443`` (it isn't, I created it for localhost) or that it is self-signed. What *exactly* does Firefox list as the reason to reject the certificate? Note also that the created name ``server.pem`` and the used name ``localhost.pem`` do not match.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, I tried with the same hostname too: 'localhost' I also tried out this package: https://github.com/talhasch/pyhttps

Firefox says:
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Also this certificate was added to the Firefox trust Authorities.